# Real Time Update not working for some fields?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time-updates

I'm checking wich fields from the User object are susceptible to RTU (real time updates); in the documentation it says:

> The User object supports Real-Time Updates for all fields except the
>   verified property.

But, so far, for this fields:

- video upload limits television significant other favorite_teams
  favorite_athletes political interested_in bio updated_time
  third_party_id gender user_likes languages

I've got this message:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#100) \"SOME_FIELD\" is an invalid field name","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

My application has the necessary permissions, checked by using this method (taken from  [this url](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)):

> https://api.facebook.com/method/users.hasAppPermission?ext_perm=SOME_PERMISSION&uid=UID&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_FOR_MY_APP

Am I missing something? Those fields are working for someone else or is just me?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried the same. Facebook seems to be a little slow here. They did not implement all fields in the RTU. You can find a list of available fields here (under objects): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/
However, even this list does not seem correct, as I did not get for example television to work either.
It is kind of odd to ask for the object "user" to get notifications about you page.. This all does not seem to be finished yet..

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer...I'm not alone here it seems. It would be nice to have all the connections working also.